# How to restore state of activity after back button has been pressed?

Tags: java, android

Hello. It is a bit difficult to make you understand the situation I am stuck in. I tried to find answers about this here on StackOverflow but it didn't help so here is the APK file attached.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/r5mengjfe4moxug/JustAnotherMusicPlayer.apk

In the app, when the music is being played and then I press the back button the activity is destroyed. And then when I try to access that activity again, from a notification, the music stops and the information that was displayed is also lost. How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

impliment this method and start the same activity again

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed();

// start your activity here 
}
```

Comment: here is a scenario...suppose activty B is open,
the user presses the back button and then i automatically activity A pops up(because of activity stack)
now i press the home button
and then i click on the notification button
.Now i want to restore the state of activity B.
how to do it?